# Can't update daterangepicker value

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a **date range picker** on my page and it works all right except that once I pick the range the value doesn't update.

I'd say that this might be because once the date range is picked up it automatically does the search for the records, so I tried to update the value based on the

```
request.args.get("start_date") and request.args.get("last_date")
```

using js

```
document.getElementById('').value = '';
```

but it doesn't work.

Does anybody have any idea why I am not able to update the value?

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: true
  }, function(start, end) {
    window.location.search = 'start_date=' + start.format("DD/MM/YYYY") + "&last_date=" + end.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    document.getElementById('daterange').value = start.format("DD/MM/YYYY") + " - " + end.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  });
});
</script>


            <div class="col-md-12 center-block" style="padding-bottom: 2rem">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="daterange" name="daterange" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
```